# Replace google-collect Lists.newArrayList() with other List

Tags: java, twitter, arraylist, guava, twitter-hbc

using Eclipse Luna I am trying to run a java code which imports deprecated google-collections, which is throwing an exception when compiled with latest Guava version.

```
public static void run(String consumerKey, String consumerSecret, String token, String secret) throws InterruptedException
{

    BlockingQueue<String> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>(10000);
    StatusesFilterEndpoint endpoint = new StatusesFilterEndpoint();
    endpoint.trackTerms(Lists.newArrayList("twitterapi", "#AAPSweep"));
    Authentication auth = new OAuth1(consumerKey, consumerSecret, token, secret);

    Client client = new ClientBuilder()
    .hosts(Constants.STREAM_HOST)
    .endpoint(endpoint)
    .authentication(auth)
    .processor(new StringDelimitedProcessor(queue))
    .build();

    client.connect();
```

I have tried to remove com.google.guava_15.0.0.v201403281430 file from plugins and tried to paste Guava old version as told [here in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9222665/nosuchmethod-error-getting-a-gdata-service) but i am unable to install(point) towards old guava version.
Also there could be another solution for this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9980915/lists-newarraylist-vs-new-arraylist) but I am new to java and dont know how to replace that List with other one.

Please is there any one can run that code using other List method ?
OR
Tell me how to add older version of Guava in eclipse (I am not sure that would solve that problem just read it from a thread)
OR
Tell me other solution. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Guava `Lists.newArrayList` is just a short-hand to create a standard JDK `ArrayList` and fill it with predefined values. You can do this in a little longer way without any third-party library using [`Arrays.asList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29):

```
endpoint.trackTerms(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("twitterapi", "#AAPSweep")));
```

Or even simpler if you don't need the structural changes in the created list:

```
endpoint.trackTerms(Arrays.asList("twitterapi", "#AAPSweep"));
```